# Why does structured binding declaration call destructor?

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

I would like to use a structured binding declaration to bring members of a struct into scope. I hope that the optimizer is able to remove the variables I don't actually use, but that's not my primary question. I got bitten by a destructor call I didn't expect:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct S {
  int x = 0;
  S() { cout << "S: " << this << endl; }
  ~S() { cout << "~S: " << this << endl; }
};

// Why does f() call ~S()?
void f(S const& s) {
  auto [x] {s};
  cout << "f: " << x << endl;
}

void g(S const& s) {
  auto& [x] {s};
  cout << "g: " << x << endl;
}

void h(S const& s) {
  auto x = s.x;
  cout << "h: " << x << endl;
}

int main(int, char**) {
  S s;
  f(s);
  g(s);
  h(s);
}
```

Running above program yields:

```
S: 0x7fff32c81778
f: 0
~S: 0x7fff32c81740
g: 0
h: 0
~S: 0x7fff32c81778
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cjeTnvx8G

The destructor call at the end of `main()` is expected. But why does `f()` call `~S()`?

I've read the documentation on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) but apparently I don't understand C++'s inner workings well enough to spot why this causes a destructor call.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? `x` is an `S` in automatic storage. Were you expecting it to bind as `const S&`?

Comment: Also, it helps to output `this` in your constructor and destructor, so that you know what object is being created and destroyed, and not merely print out `~S` or `f: `.  If you see a `this` in the destructor that mysteriously shows up without a corresponding `this` in the constructor, then you know that you are not tracking all the constructors that are being called.

Comment: RE Brian61354270 and Holt: `x` is an `int`. Note that `operator<<` is not defined for `S`, so if `x` were an `S` the program wouldn't compile.

Comment: RE PaulMcKenzie: I've updated the question and the link to godbolt.

Comment: @jonas-schulze `0x7fff32c81740` -- You see that you didn't track the constructor for the object that is being destroyed.  Things like the copy constructor and move constructor for `S` are not being outputted with your code.

Comment: [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/MTjf1ojc5).  That outputs that a copy is being made, and it is the copy that is being destroyed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am wording this not as a language lawyer, but hope to give some intuition how structured bindings work.

When you read

```
auto [key, value] = foo();
```

replace for a moment the `[key, value]` part by an invented name:

```
auto invented_name = foo();
```

Now it is obvious that the code holds onto an instance of the value returned by `foo()`. Furthermore, if there are any reference specifiers or cv qualifiers, they apply to the invented name. I.e.,

```
const auto& [key, value] = foo();
```

becomes

```
const auto& invented_name = foo();
```

and ditto for `&&`. Reference and cv qualifiers do *not* apply to the names `key` and `value` (but other rules achieve that they basically behave as if they were applied).

The names `key` and `value` now merely become aliases for the first and second structure members of `invented_name` (or the return values of `get<0>(invented_name)` and `get<1>(invented_name)`).

Comment: "Otherwise e is defined as if by using its name instead of [ identifier-list ] in the declaration." :facepalm:

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

> A structured binding declaration first introduces a uniquely-named variable (here denoted by `e`) to hold the value of the initializer, as follows:...
>
> We use `E` to denote the type of the expression `e`. (In other words, `E` is the equivalent of `std::remove_reference_t<decltype((e))>`.)...
>
> A structured binding declaration then performs the binding in one of three possible ways, depending on `E`:... if `E` is a non-union class type..., then the names are bound to the accessible data members of `E`....
>
> Each identifier in identifier-list becomes the name of an lvalue that refers to the next member of e in declaration order

My reading of this is that, in cases like yours, a structured binding effectively creates a local `e` from the expression, and then uses tuple-like methods to bind references to the initializer list.

```
void f(S const& s) {
  using E = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(s)>;
  E e{s}; //expression
  const int& x = e.x; //initializer list

  cout << "f: " << x << endl;
}

void g(S const& s) {
  using E = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(s)>;
  E& e{s}; //expression
  const int& x = e.x; //initializer list

  cout << "g: " << x << endl;
}
```

And therefore what you're seeing is the destructor of the temporary `E e;`

[Chris_se](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17385571/chris-se) has helpfully linked to https://cppinsights.io/s/239fcf14, which is a tool that shows explicit interpretations of C++ code.

Comment: Wouldn't the initializer list be `x`? Also, I'm only seeing the constructor of `S` being called once but not twice for a potential temporary.

Comment: @jonas-schulze: One sentence had the wrong words. Fixed.  The `E e` *is* the temporary.

Comment: Note that your code doesn't compile. `operator<<` is not defined for `S` and `x` is not an `S`.

Comment: @jonas-schulze: My question was *very* wrong at first, so I deleted it and fixed it, but apparently missed that `x` was not S in one spot. Fixed that too.

Comment: To add to this answer, C++ Insights will tell you what the compiler is doing: https://cppinsights.io/s/239fcf14

Comment: RE @MooingDuck: Thanks, this was helpful as well. Could you please edit the answer for `E = ... <S const&>` and `int const& x = e.x`? Stackoverflow won't let me...

Comment: RE @chris_se: Thanks, will check it out.

Comment: @jonas-schulze: I changed the `E` to use `decltype`, and changed the `x` to `int const&`, thanks for those corrections.